# Can you pass a SwiftUI ForEach identifer as a parameter?

Tags: swiftui

I have a generic struct that takes a list of objects, and displays a list of checkboxes. This uses generics so I can pass in any type of object (the struct also takes a function parameter to tell it how to get the display text from the object).

The ForEach uses `id:\.self` as the identifier, and this works fine as long as the objects are identifiable and hashable.

However, this is part of a KMM project, and sometimes the objects I'm working with aren't identifiable/hashable. I can work around this by using an explicit identifier (e.g. `id:\.uuid`), but this is resulting in a bunch of duplicated code as I can't use my generic view.

Is it possible to pass the identifier to the struct as a parameter with self being the default? I.e. I'd like to do something like:
`var forEachIdentifier = T.self` and then use it like `ForEach(options, id: forEachIndentifier){...`

Here's the full struct:

```
struct SelectMultipleChoiceDialog<T:Hashable>: View {
    var onDismissRequest: () -> Void
    var title: String
   var  options: [T]
   var  selectedOptions: [T]
   var  text: (T) -> String
   var  onCheckedChange: (T, Bool) -> Void
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView{
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(options, id:\.self){option in
                        
                        HStack{
                            Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {
                                selectedOptions.contains(option)
                            }, set: { value in
                                onCheckedChange(option, value)
                            })){
                            }
                            .toggleStyle(iOSCheckboxToggleStyle())
                            
                            Text(text(option))
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 6)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(title)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Done"){
               onDismissRequest()
            
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use small View structs to reuse code instead.

Best just remove `Hashable` and `id: /.self` and you won't have this problem. `ForEach` is designed to use `Identifiable` so when options change it can do a diff and update the underlying UIViews.

You said "objects" rather than values though, in that case you don't even need Identifable since objects are already identified by their pointer.

Seems to me you want to write to the options, the syntax for that is:

```
ForEach($options){ $option in
```

If you put the Toggle in a custom View then you can use onChange to do your action and don't need the closure.

Comment: The problem with this is that it requires $option to be identifiable, and as I mentioned, I am sometimes working with objects that aren't identifiable. However, I think I've found the answer using   `ForEach(Array(options.enumerated()), id:\.offset){index, option in...`

Comment: Objects are identifiable by default. You can't use ForEach with indicies like that, it'll crash.

Comment: If I use your way I get an error `Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'T' conform to 'Identifiable'` - if I use the indicies approach it works perfectly with no crashes.

Comment: It will crash when the options array changes because an index is not an identifier so when you look up the array by index it can be out of range.